# convert 0.xxx float value to X "power of" in c#

Tags: c#

Hi2,

I have this "really many commas behind" values, like this: 
*0.0000123456789*

I only know how to cut string to six digit with:

```
someString.ToString("f6"));
```

which resulting in *0.000012*

But, how do i convert it to: 
*12.34 E-6* ? ( I only want to have 2 digit after commas)

and vice versa, when the value is

*123456789* I want it to be converted to
*12.34 E+6*

so basically i always want to have the format as "xx.xx E+x" or "xx.xx E-x"

any help is appreciated... ^^,

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#EFormatString

Comment: Give `someValue.ToString("##.##E+0");` a try

Comment: If you want "two digits after the comma" why is your required result "12.34 E-6" instead of the actual scientific notation value of "1.23 E-5", or the also non-standard value of "123.45 E-7"?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen: of course!!!! why i didn't think that of thatt...!!
Thank youuu verrryy muchhh Mathiassss!! :D
*you should turn that to answer rather than commenting... ^^,

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Is that functionality (non-standard scientific notation) documented somewhere? I've never seen it used that way and was shocked that it worked.  I'd be concerned that it was an undocumented feature that is subject to change.

Comment: @DStanley I'm afraid I can't find anything that explicitly says "`E` will honor the rounding caused by `#`", that's... (fortunately) just the way the composite formatting works out.